# How to add a parent category for my parent category? hashmap

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

I have this listview that has childs (Wall Pushup etc.) in a parent category (Beginner_Ex). How do I make a 'grandparent' for the parents?

--
I now have:

Parent
--Child
--Child
--Child

What I want is:

Grandparent
---Parent
------Child
------Child

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo()
{
    HashMap<String, List<String>> ExDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> Beginner_Ex = new ArrayList<String>();
    Beginner_Ex.add("Wall Pushup");
    Beginner_Ex.add("Knee Pushup");
    Beginner_Ex.add("Regular Pushup");
    Beginner_Ex.add("Assisted Pullup");
    Beginner_Ex.add("Leg Raise on Ground");

    ExDetails.put("Beginner", Beginner_Ex);
    ExDetails.put("Experienced", Experi_Ex);
    ExDetails.put("Advanced", Advanced_Ex);
    ExDetails.put("Expert", Expert_Ex);
    ExDetails.put("Impossible", Imposs_Ex);

    return ExDetails;
```

Comment: `ExDetails.put("grandParentA", Beginner_Ex)`?

Comment: Could you give a little more detail about what you're trying to do? I'm guessing these are exercises in the "Beginner_Ex" category, and then you might have an "Intermediate_Ex" category with other exercises. What would be an example of a grandparent category?

Comment: I have this list of exercises catagorized by parents, like beginner_ex. I also want to catagorize all the parents like beginner_ex to a 'grandparent' catagory namely 'Difficulity'.

Comment: Let me know if that's easier to understand!

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? Using **Multi-level HashMaps**..

[Best Practices for Using Multi Level HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422443/best-practices-for-using-multi-level-hashmap-in-java)

Comment: Oh damn. I thought it be a easy one-liner of code. Rip.

Comment: Is there no easier way?